# Maven EAR building in local but not in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, parent-pom, maven-ear-plugin

we are doing a maven conversion for an existing project which is in ant.
this project has so many sub modules in it.
**Parent POM looks like below**:

```
...
  <module>p1</module>
  <module>p2</module>
  <module>p3</module>
  <module>p4_WAR</module>
  <module>p5_EJB1</module>
  <module>p5_EJB2</module>
  <module>p5_EJB3</module>
  <module>Final_EAR</module>
...
```

where p1,p2,p3... are subprojects which are having their own POMs being called from parent POM. These sub project POMs can be executed to build them individually.

This parent POM calls the subprojects POMs and finally builds them as an EAR in Final_EAR project POM. This is success in local machine but when I do the same in Jenkins it is failing with below exception.

[Problem creating zip: Execution exception in Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxwQ5.jpg)

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Jenkins. Try with a different BuildSlave.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the whole log output in particular the area of Maven EAR Plugin...

Comment: change your build command in Jenkins to have more details: `mvn -X`